# html <applet> hidden params

Tags: java, html, applet

I have a java applet on a page in this format:

In order for the application to work, these two parameters must be passed to it or else it won't allow the user to connect.  Obviously, these parameters can be crawled/scraped which is something I want to stop. I know that if you don't want people to get something, don't put it on the internet; there has to be a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have tried using ioncube loader, html "obfuscators", and all of them are able to be decoded easily.  The main goal is for this .jar to be able to get these parameters and allow access to my service via a web browser, but not have them visible to the public.  Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Are these values the same for every user? Or are they different depending on who views the applet?

Comment: If they are the same OP would not pass them as inputs perhaps, he would know them in the Applet..

Comment: They are the same for every user.  Having them in the client is pointless as the clan can be decompiled, obfuscated or not.

Comment: @SHH Well, yes and no. If someone has the ability to decompile the app, they have the ability to watch it in memory too. No amount of encryption can stop that. If it's the same for every person, having them in the app is safe.

Comment: *"there has to be a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish"*  Why?  And no, I think you are wrong.  But more importantly, what are the two parameters, narrow it down for us..  Are they username/password, sex and hat size..?

Comment: The two parameters are key1 and key2.  The server requires that the client have both of those keys in order to accept the connection.

Answer (score -1):

Implement some thing like SHA encryption both sides (in Java Script and in the applet).

```
Java Script side : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html
Java Side (applet) : http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/
```

Comment: @corsika - Did the original poster ask for a hash solution?

Answer (score -1):

Don't make them start-up parameters.

Instead, have your applet load up, and the first thing it does is contact another web service to acquire the values. This way, you have a variety of methods at your disposal to implement the encryption, and you never have to put it in the HTML.

This will also help you if/when you decide to port the application, for example to a mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The problem with that is this:  If the applet contacts a web service to get the keys, then the web service would obviously only accept requests from a specific client.  If the applet could be decompiled then whatever values that make it the "specific client" would be available for anyone to use in their own applications.  See my dilemma?

Comment: No, I don't see your dilemma. If someone has the ability to decompile your app, then they have the ability to reverse engineer ANY kind of scheme you have to protect your data, no matter how complicated it is.